# Sending date in json body in a post request via POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, json, postman

I want to add Date Of birth to my user documents in mongodb user collection under a specific key called DOB. So for that i need to pass it via postman. Can anyone help me with the format that i need to use in postman? 
i want to do something like this:

```
{
"name": "XYZ",
"dob" : 12/11/1981
}
```

Please notice that in schema definition dob is type: Date.

Answer (score 9):

Pass date as string from client side and convert it into the date from server side is the best approach.

clientside

```
{
"name": "XYZ",
"dob" : "12/11/1981"
}
```

Server side:

```
const date = new Date(req.body.dob)
```

Comment: Is there  no way to send date format via postman? Your approach is good, i had teh same in mind, but i am looking to explore postman a bit more.

Comment: It's not part of a postman. This is part of the data structure. The data you are sending neither string nor a numeric value. It has to be a proper JSON format.  You can validate your format from this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ link.